# Silence Character Length Print in File Write

Tags: python, printing

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write('stuff')
    output.write('hello there')
```

**Output:**

```
5
11
```

How do I silence the those printed character lengths (5, 11)?

Comment: Are you trying this in the REPL? Have you tried executing it as a script and seeing if that solves your problem?

Comment: are you using jupiter notebook? the output shouldn't go through `stdout`, it's just the returned value - in a script you can just ignore it like @JohnOss said

Comment: From the [docs for `write`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html): *"f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written."* (This behavior was introduced in python3- in python2 this returned `None`). I am guessing, as blue-phoenox said, that you are running these line by line in an interpreter. Check the contents of `file.txt` - it should be correct.

Comment: Python shells typically print the output of a line, but scripts don't. If you find it annoying, assign the result to a variable `foo = output.write('stuff')``

Comment: @tdelaney if you'd like to write that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python shells assume users want to see what's going on as the program executes. They don't display assignments, but they do display just about everything else. Normally that's useful

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> foo
1
>>> os.path.isfile('file.txt')
False
>>>
```

But it can get too chatty

```
>>> with open('file.txt', 'w') as output:
...     output.write('stuff')
... 
5
>>>
```

If you are running a shell and you want to reduce the chatter, you can assign the function's return value to a throwaway variable. By tradition in python, that's `_`

```
>>> 
>>> with open('file.txt', 'w') as output:
...     _ = output.write('stuff')
... 
>>>
```